# What is the boost equivalent of std::vector<T>::iterator?

Tags: c++, boost

What is the boost equivalent of

```
std::vector<T> v;  // Assume this was initialized properly
std::vector<T>::iterator it, e = v.end();
for ( it = v.begin() ; it != e ; ++it ) {
    // do something with 'v' via *it
}
```

I'm using a boost vector

```
boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T> v;
```

Can someone give match the above example using proper boost syntax?

Comment: Isn't it `boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T>::iterator`?

Comment: I've edited a few of your previous questions to remove your signature. Signatures on Stack Exchange are very discouraged. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yeah, I thought so, but I'm having a terrible time with it. Maybe the compiler is just freaking out about something else. I will investigate.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Preliminarily it looks as if I've fallen victim to needing the keyword "typename"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is:

```
typename boost::numeric::ublas::vector<T>::iterator
```

See documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector.htm

Comment: I appreciate your response, please refrain from words like "quite obviously", because if it was so obvious to me, I wouldn't have made a fool of myself to ask.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to offend you.